# как выполнить метод после некоторого времени?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, многопоточность, клиент-сервер, сервлеты

Я пишу систему заказа такси, и у меня есть сервлет Booking, в котором выполняется действие по бронированию такси, сразу после бронирования конкретной  машины, ей ставиться флаг 'занята', как мне правильно сделать освобождения машины после например 2 минут после заказа?Через потоки, Timer, Scheduler ?

```
package com.taxi.controller;


@WebServlet("/booking")
public class BookingServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
   private StreetDao streetDao = new StreetDaoImpl();
   private TaxiDao taxiDao = new TaxiDaoImpl();
   private WayDao wayDao = new WayDaoImpl();
   private BookingDao bookingDao = new BookingDaoImpl();
   private ActionDao actionDao = new ActionDaoImpl();
   private UserActionDao userActionDao = new UserActionDaoImpl();



    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Street> streets = streetDao.getAllStreets();
        req.setAttribute("streets", streets);

        List<Taxi> taxis = taxiDao.getAllAvailableCars();
        req.setAttribute("taxis", taxis);



        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String usName = session.getAttribute("user").toString();

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(userDao.getIdByUserName(usName));
        user.setUserName(usName);


        String home = req.getParameter("home");
        String dest = req.getParameter("dest");

        //Get available car
        Taxi taxi = taxiDao.getCarByCarType(car);
        //Get streets home and dest
        Street homeStreet = new Street(home);
        homeStreet.setId(streetDao.getStreetIdByName(home));
        Street destStreet = new Street(dest);
        destStreet.setId(streetDao.getStreetIdByName(dest));


        //get sum km of way
        double km = wayDao.getSumKm(homeStreet,destStreet);

        System.out.println(km + "km");
        System.out.println("USER DETAILS: " + user.toString());

        Action action = actionDao.getUserAction(user);
        UserAction userAction = userActionDao.getUserActionByAction(action);
        //get user discount


        //Get price
        double price = km * 11;
        if(action.getDiscount() > 20){
            price = price- action.getDiscount();
        }else{
            actionDao.addSumToAction(user, action, price%10);
        }


        Booking booking = new Booking();
        booking.setUser(user);
        booking.setHome(homeStreet);
        booking.setDest(destStreet);
        booking.setTaxi(taxi);

        booking.setAction(userAction);
        booking.setPrice(price);

       // bookingDao.book(booking);
       // taxi.setIs_free(false);
       // taxiDao.setCarBusy(taxi);
       // taxiDao.changeCurrentPos(taxi, destStreet);
        //TODO set taxi to free after some time 
        //taxiDao.setCarFree(taxi);

        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/view/bookingtaxi.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов как это сделать достаточно много. Не советую делать подобные вещи через треды или in-memory задачи, потому что тогда вы рискуете, в случае падения приложения, потерять список машин, которые нужно освободить.
На мой взгляд самое простое и достаточно эффективное решение - это сохранять информацию о смене статуса машины в какое нибудь персистентное хранилище (вы же наверняка используете БД), а затем по расписанию запускать воркера, который будет выбирать из хранилища список машин, для которых подошло время, и обновлять их статус.